# Find equal instance in a c++ set

Tags: c++

I'm using a c++ STL set and I want to know if it's present in the set an equivalent instance. To retrive the instance I'm using the find set method. The problem is that it doesn't work. I think the problem is in my comparator object:

```
bool SetComparator::operator ()( const Point* i1, const Point* i2 ) const {
    if ( *i1 == *i2 )
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

The operator == is redefined for the class Point in a simple way:

```
bool Point::operator ==( const Point& p ) const {
     if (x == p.x && y == p.y)
         return true;
     return false;
}
```

After a debugging I can see that the find method calls operator() but it doesn't find the same instance so the find returns end() but I know that there is an equal object. I think the problem is related to the set internal order. How can I do?

Comment: in your `SetComparator::operator()`you return false if the 2 Point compare true. Is that normal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::set uses partial ordering (i.e. the `operator<`), so when you pass in an operator that can only decide equality, you break the assumption of the implementation of std::set. Your SetComparator has to behave similar to `std::less`.

For example std::pair (utility) implements [relational operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/operators/) for two items, e.g. for `operator<`:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator< (const std::pair<T1,T2>& lhs, const std::pair<T1,T2>& rhs) {
    return lhs.first<rhs.first || (!(rhs.first<lhs.first) && lhs.second<rhs.second);
}
```

note that `(!(rhs.first<lhs.first) && lhs.second<rhs.second)` is a workaround for `(rhs.first == lhs.first && lhs.second < rhs.second)` using only `operator<`

If you only want to check for equality maybe using std::set is the wrong decision. If you can hash your objects, you could use a [std::unordered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) (C++11 and later).

Comment: How can I use a less if I have got x and y?

Comment: The unordered_set is ok but I can't use c++11

Comment: @greywolf82 depending on the amount of elements and number of searches you do, did you consider using an array? linear searches are super fast too.

Comment: I need a lot of elements, so a simple array doesn't work in this case.